# Best solution to retry AWS lambda function when it got timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a serious question and I need your help. I can not find any solution on the Internet after spending a lot of time.

I made a bot to get data which is really heavy task because I need to setup a scraper and then it extract data from a webpage through many steps (login, logout, click, submit button, ...) and after got this result, it will post to an API to make a report.

I use Cloudwatch event to make my lambda function run in certain time every day.

The problem is although I set my lambda function in its max settings (3GB RAM, and 15 minutes timeout, the metrics is in Jan 2019), but sometime my lambda function failed when executing (maybe the scrape tasks take too lot of steps or maybe the webpage I tried to scrape is not stable) and it rarely failed, about only 5% I think.

But I want to know if there is any approach to deal with this situation, I want my lambda function can be auto retry when it fail without doing manual.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfect example for a `StepFunction` you can have it scheduled by CloudWatch Event instead of the lambda.

The `StepFunction` can call your lambda and handle the retry logic on failure with configurable exponential back-off if needed.

Here is an example of a StepFunction

```
{
  "Comment": "Call lambda with retry",
  "StartAt": "Scraper",
  "States": {
    "Scraper": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "<LAMBDA_ARN>",
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 20,
          "MaxAttempts": 5,
          "BackoffRate": 2
        }
      ],
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your lambda is already retried because a trigger from a cloudwatch event is async. (see the docs below)
I would set up a DLQ for your lambda, and then reprocess from there.

From the docs ([aws lambda event sources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html))

> Error handling for a given event source depends on how Lambda is invoked. Amazon CloudWatch Events invokes your Lambda function asynchronously. For more information on how errors are retried, see AWS Lambda Retry Behavior.
>
> And: ([aws lambda retry behaviour](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/retries-on-errors.html))
>
> Asynchronous invocation – Asynchronous events are queued before being used to invoke the Lambda function. If AWS Lambda is unable to fully process the event, it will automatically retry the invocation twice, with delays between retries. If you have specified a Dead Letter Queue for your function, then the failed event is sent to the specified Amazon SQS queue or Amazon SNS topic. If you don't specify a Dead Letter Queue (DLQ), which is not required and is the default setting, then the event will be discarded. For more information, see AWS Lambda Function Dead Letter Queues.

Comment: Your lambda is already retried because a trigger from a cloudwatch event is async =>
It is really weird, I do not know why but some day, I could not get any result because my function is failed when executing.

================================================================================
I  would set up a DLQ for your lambda, and then reproces from there. => I will give it a try about it and will feedback to you soon

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer has already been given, in this article I explain the problem and share an example of step functions handling lambdas.

[Lambdas with step function](https://medium.com/engineering-compono/stop-having-errors-in-your-event-driven-service-after-this-serverless-design-change-8b0f90400f3b)